# Laravel + Postgres Filter Program Based on Result

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I need a logic or suggestions on filtering program based on result. Let say the result in form of number which:

Result of a student,

| Subject | Grade |
| --- | --- |
| (1011) English | A |
| (1449) Mathematics | D |
| (2100) History | B |
| (1211) Biology | A |
| (1112) Computing | C |

Grade reference:

| Value | Grade |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | D |
| 5 | E |

Program qualification,

| Program | Minimum Requirement |
| --- | --- |
| (CS101) Computer Science | Mathematics - C, Computing - C |
| (NS102) Nursing | Biology - C |
| (AC101) Accounting | Mathematics - D |
| (TS103) TESL | English - B |

So the program that is not qualified based on result will not be displayed when student click the dropdown.

In this case, only Nursing, Accounting and TESL will appear.

My current code only filter Mathematics. I count the grade. Count > 0 means the subject is not meet qualification.

```
$count_result = Result::where('app_id', $request->app_id)->where('subject_code', '1449')->where('grade_code', '>', '3')->count();
                    
                    //check result math C, if not, exlude CS101
                    if ($count_result > 0) {
                    
                        $data = OfferedProgram::select("offered_program.id as id", "offered_program.sts as sts", "branches.name as branch_name", "courses.name as course_name")
                        ->join("branch_course", "branch_course.id", "=", "offered_program.branch_course_id")
                        ->join("branches", "branches.id", "=", "branch_course.branch_id")
                        ->join("courses", "courses.id", "=", "branch_course.course_id")
                        ->where("session_id", request()->session_id)
                        ->where("offered_program.sts", true)
                        ->where('offered_program.total_quota', '>', 0)
                        ->whereIn("courses.level", [1,2])
                        ->whereNotIn('courses.code', ['CS101'})
                        ->get();
                    } else {
// display all programs
                        $data = OfferedProgram::select("offered_program.id as id", "offered_program.sts as sts", "branches.name as branch_name", "courses.name as course_name")
                        ->join("branch_course", "branch_course.id", "=", "offered_program.branch_course_id")
                        ->join("branches", "branches.id", "=", "branch_course.branch_id")
                        ->join("courses", "courses.id", "=", "branch_course.course_id")
                        ->where("session_id", request()->session_id)
                        ->where("offered_program.sts", true)
                        ->where('offered_program.total_quota', '>', 0)
                        ->whereIn("courses.level", [1,2])
                        ->get();
                    }
```

How do I filter for another programs?

Comment: Can you add related table column , it is more easy for us to help you.

Comment: Basically it only involve those 3 table. The join in eloquent is use to retrieve additional information only

Comment: How do you store minimum requirements for programs in your database?

Comment: program requirement is stored in requirement table. It consist program id, subject code and minimum subject grade